# Media queries being not accurate

Tags: css, google-chrome, sass, media-queries

I'm using Google Chrome as my default browser for coding and noticed weird behavior a while ago but it's today that I want to know if this is correct.

Simple example:
My media query is set like this:

```
@media (max-width: 1350px) {
    th.column-hidden, td.column-hidden {
      display: none;
    }
}
```

Based on this the column with the mentioned class should not be visible until 1350px point is met.

When I resize my browser screen I can see the indicator at the top right corner, and the column dissappears at around 1215px. What might be causing this inaccuracy?

One thing that I noticed is that my macbook screen resolution is `2560x1600`, but [www.whatismyscreenresolution.com](https://www.whatismyscreenresolution.com/) shows `1440x900`

**edit**
I've just entered an example of other page that uses media queries and those are accurate. And they do differ at all.

Comment: Can you give a test page, or a screenshot? What's your browser zoom level?

Comment: I'm using `https://ant.design/components/grid/` grid system. On their page (Chrome) the media queries are accurate, and on the app that I'm working on they are applied inaccurately. Unfortunately I can't share any of the pages :(

Comment: My page zoom im `chrome://settings` is set to `100%`

Comment: Actually, I have no idea why, but it started to work. In the meantime I commented my `manifest.json` file `link` in the `head` tag but I uncommented it again. I changed my browser zoom to 50% and then back to 100%. Maybe that has helped. But it's weird that it affected only me app.

Answer (score 0):

Your MacBook's physical resolution is in fact 1440x900. The retina aspect of the display means it has a higher DPI (dots per inch), which makes it display a higher resolution. Browsers don't take DPI into affect, but simply your physical resolution.

Comment: Thanks for that. Any idea how can I make this media queries be accurate?

Comment: No problem. Check out this link: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/ Chris Coyier does a great job of explaining technical things like this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use pixer ratio like this:

```
/* 1.25 dpr */
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.25), (min-resolution: 120dpi) {
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}

/* 1.3 dpr */
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.3), (min-resolution: 124.8dpi) {
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}

/* 1.5 dpr */
@media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5), (min-resolution: 144dpi) {
    /* Retina-specific stuff here */
}
```